# Showing Manually Entered Data Based on TableView Click Using Firebase

Tags: uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app where I have a list of data that I manually enter into Firebase. Here is an image of the Firebase Database:

[image]

When the user selects an index row, it goes into another view controller. Inside that view controller there is a tableview, which I want to populate with the data from the “name” that I selected.

For example, if I select the “name” from [acct0], I want the “name” and “genre” to also appear in the new tableview.

Currently, I am trying to print the data based on the selection in the previous view controller.

```
let user = User()

ref?.child("FeaturedAccounts/AccountNames").child(user.name!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    let userDict = snapshot.value as! [String: Any]
    let genre = userDict["genre"] as! String
        print("Genre: \(genre)")
        print(user.name!)
})
```

Comment: What's the current issue? Are you getting an error or no data?

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct to me. It's hard to say exactly what is going wrong without more information. Here is some code you can use to help debug your issue. If you post some more of your code or explain exactly what is currently happening with your query I can help more.

```
let user = User()
let ref = Database.database().reference()

ref.child("FeaturedAccounts").child("AccountNames").child(user.name!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
    if snapshot.exists() {
        print(snapshot.value)
    }
    else {
        print("Query returned no data")
    }

    if let userDict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
        if let genre = userDict["genre"] as? String {
                print("Genre: \(genre)")
        }
        else {
            print("could not cast genre to string")
        }
    }
    else {
        print("Could not cast userDict")
    }
})
```

Comment: I am getting "query returned no data" and "could not cast userDict". I believe that I am not passing the data from the previously view controller correctly.

Comment: Post your user class. That query isn't getting data if that's printing. Try manually entering the value you're trying to use.